# Does MariaDB support renaming an index?

Tags: sql, indexing, alter-table, mariadb

Is there a syntax for renaming an index in MariaDB?  I understand that MySQL 5.7 supports the syntax, but does MariaDB 10.0 (which includes MySQL 5.6) support it?

Comment: Have you tried anything? You can always drop the index and recreate it using a another name.

Comment: Yes, I know I can drop/create the index.  We have some complex code that is shared between various database vendors that already does an index rename.  Was hoping this could easily be done by MariaDB

Comment: [MariaDB 10.5.2](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-1052-release-notes/) (still unreleased) will have the `ALTER TABLE ... RENAME INDEX` feature.

Answer (score 9):

I just tried `ALTER TABLE thing RENAME INDEX ix_old TO ix_new;` in MariaDB 10.2.12 and it failed.

It also doesn't appear in the docs at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/alter-table/

And mysteriously an answer to this question displayed in duckduckgo doesn't exist! It said

> No, there is no way to rename an index in current versions of MySQL
>   (up to 5.6) or MariaDB (up to 10) or Percona Server (up to 5.6).
>
> You can only drop an index and create a new index of a different name.
>
> As a workaround, you could use pt-online-schema-change to add a new
>   index with the new name and drop the old index by its old name, while
>   allowing continuous read/write access to the original table.
>
> $ pt-online-schema-change --alter "ADD KEY new_idx_name, DROP KEY
>   old_idx_name" \   D=mydatabase,t=mytable
>
> --Bill Karwin

But Bill Karwin's edit to the question remains. Hmmm, why would he have deleted it?

Comment: Worked fine in MariaDB 10.5.9.

Answer (score 2):

They added the option on version 10.5.2, but I'm not sure it works because I have the vs 10.3 in my servers.  https://mariadb.com/kb/en/alter-table/#rename-indexkey

I'll update it with more info.